# Incompatible conditional operand types String and s2 instanceof

Tags: java

This code

```
    String s1,s2;
    if(s1 instanceof s2) {

    }
```

is giving me error:
Incompatible conditional operand types String and s2. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 6):

You need a **Class** on the right  hand side of this operator, not an **instance of a class**.

For runtime checking if an object is an instance of a class of another object, you can use the tools in the [Class class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

```
if(s2.getClass().isAssignableFrom(s1.getClass))

...
```

> [isAssignableFrom(Class cls)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)
>
> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Or there is the `isInstance(Object)` call for a similar situation:

```
if(s2.getClass().isInstance(s1))
 ....
```

> [isInstance(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)
>
> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot variables in `instanceof` (at least not on the right side).

The class needs to be known at compile-time, for example

```
 if (x instanceof String)
```

If that is not possible you can do

```
 if (s2.getClass().isInstance(s1))
```

(note the argument order is reversed here).

Usually, though, you don't need to do either in well-designed code. Some more context may lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, if you see Oracle tutorial:

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface

So right hand side of instanceof should be Class, an subclass or a class that implements an interface.
Try like this, this should work

```
if(s1 instance of String) //Since you have specified s1 as a string.
```

Also you need to assign to a String, else it won't compile.